# Highchart click response time

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

When i click the piece of pie chart, selection animation is playing aproximately 300 ms. How to speed up this animation or stop this animation, any idea?

[Click to see screenshot](http://s14.postimg.org/jm0fk458h/Capture.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can affect the animation usng the chart->animation options. To simply make it faster, try:

```
 chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        animation: {
            duration: 100
        }
    },
```

The full options can be found here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.animation. These can include other options such as jquery easing.

http://jsfiddle.net/3vwMH/

Answer (score 1):

**Thank you for answer.**

For c#

.InitChart(new Chart{Animation = new Animation(new AnimationConfig { Duration = 10 }),})

Comment: If an answer is correct, it is good practice to mark it as accepted to let others know that it is the right answer. You also get some reputation for doing so. Click the 'tick' mark next to the correct answer.